# Simple python folders/subfolders import example

Tags: python

I have this simple project structure:

```
    main
        __init__.py
        animal.py (class Animal)
        sub1
            __init__.py
            cat.py (class Cat)
        sub2
            __init__.py
            dog.py (class Dog)
```

Each `__init__.py` file is empty.

So,

- from `dog.py` I need to import `Animal` class

Using this syntax:

```
from animal import Animal
```

I got

```
ImportError: No module named animal
```

- from `dog.py` I need to import `Cat` class in `sub1.cat` module

Using this syntax:

```
from sub1.cat import Cat
```

I got

```
ImportError: No module named sub1.cat
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your file is called `aniaml ` not `animal`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov yeah..but this is not the problem

Comment: how about `from main.animal import Animal`?

Comment: ImportError: No module named main.animal

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but to no avail. With the same exact structure and files, it works! I suppose it is something else..

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.9 in raspberry pi. Don't know if this can be helpful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)